# Complicated table calculations

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I have a dataframe df_workingFile:

```
group  | id  | flag | value |
 a     |  a  |  0   |  5    |  
 a     |  c  |  0   |  2    |  
 b     |  b  |  0   |  8    |  
 b     |  e  |  1   |  1    |
```

I want to **sum** the *value* column based on group, but only on the row where *group* = *id* (there can only be one of these instances by group). I also don't want to include any values in the sum that have a *flag*:

```
group  | id  | flag | value | ValueSum
 a     |  a  |  0   |  5    |   7
 a     |  c  |  0   |  2    |   0
 b     |  b  |  0   |  8    |   8
 b     |  e  |  1   |  1    |   0
```

Input data:

```
df_workingFile <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), id = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "e"), class = "factor"), flag = c(0, 0, 0, 1), value = c(5, 
2, 8, 1)), .Names = c("group", "id", "flag", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please `dput(head( df_workingFile))` and paste into question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: sure, just did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple with the `data.table` package. Here is my solution:

```
library(data.table)

temp <- data.table(group = c("a","a","b","b"),
           id = c("a","c","b","d"),
           flag = c(0,0,0,1),
           value = c(5,2,8,1))

temp[flag != 1,ValueSum := ifelse(group == id,sum(value), NA), by = group]
```

Before the first comma, you are able to specify a logical condition. In the middle you can do column assignment (I'm sure there's a cleaner solution in this case, but it works). After the second comma, you can specify a group-by statement. I would highly recommend getting familiar with the package, it has made my life far easier.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work with my dataframe. I think it's because you loaded your stuff in as a data.table, so I get an error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, convert it to a data.table with as.data.table.

Comment: no this still gives errors. try it with my input data

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(valueSum=ifelse(flag==0 & group==id,sum(value),0))

  group    id  flag value valueSum
  <chr> <chr> <int> <int>    <dbl>
1     a     a     0     5        7
2     a     c     0     2        0
3     b     b     0     8        9
4     b     e     1     1        0
```

Comment: this gives me errors ("level sets of factors are different") - want to refer to the data I supplied?

Also - not a huge deal, but the valueSum for row 3 should ideally be 8 (sum only takes place for not flagged rows)

Comment: That is because you have factors in your dataframe. Either precise stringsAsFactors=F when you construct or read in your dataframe. Otherwise, you can add `d$group=as.character(d$group)`
 and `d$id=as.character(d$id)`.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you could use `ave` with `sum` and `rep` to fill in the 0s for the final values.

```
df_workingFile$valueSum <-
          with(df_workingFile,
               ave(value * !flag, group, FUN=function(x) c(sum(x), rep(0, length(x)-1))))
```

This returns the desired results.

```
df_workingFile
  group id flag value valueSum
1     a  a    0     5        7
2     a  c    0     2        0
3     b  b    0     8        8
4     b  e    1     1        0
```